# Apache mod_auth_kerb

Tags: apache, mod-auth-kerb

I have a setup using apache and mod_auth_kerb to authenticate users and proxy them to the destination web server using a HTTP header with username (X-Remote-User).

How do i setup a proper logout mechanism from the destination web server?
 - URL to call or similar?

Answer (score 0):

Our setup works like this:

We have one url, which is protected by Kerberos:

```
/kerberos_login
```

Once client access it, Kerberos authentication is performed. If successful, client is redirected to `/` — this is *not* protected by Kerberos.

To log out, clients have to access logout url (that one is also *not* protected by Kerberos):

```
/logout
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, my question is mainly on how to impl. the '/logout' for this setup. Do you remove a HTTP cookie?